# Debian packaging of python library with extra files

Tags: python, deb, packaging

Is there a minimal modification I can do to a Python 3 Debian package source in order to install additional folders under the `dist-utils/my-package` folder like unit tests? I am using `pybuild` which relies on `setup.py` script in the background but I would prefer not to modify the `setup.py` and use `install` or some other configuration file within the Debian packaging.

I checked links like

https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-module_packages.html

and

https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide?action=show&redirect=Python%2FPackaging

but I couldn't find anything to help me accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most default solution is to create a **debian/install** template for the package with contents like:

```
./tests/* usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proj1/tests/
./misc/* usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proj1/misc/
```

Another way is to update project's **debian/rules** as:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --with python3 --buildsystem=pybuild

override_dh_install:
    dh_install ./test/* usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proj1/tests/
    dh_install ./misc/* usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/proj1/tests/
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a different file name for the destination with the `debian/install` file? Or is the last parameter always a directory?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible. You could try with files instead of directories and see how it goes.